# C If condition not accepting argument

Tags: c

I'm new to C and I'm trying to use an if statement to check for an argument (in this case "jobs") but it doesn't seem to be working...

```
int builtin_cmd(char **argv)
{
  printf("test1\n");
  if (!strcmp(argv[0], "quit")) { //quit command
    exit(0);
  }
  if ((!strcmp(argv[0], "fg")) || (!strcmp(argv[0], "bg"))) { //fg or bg command
    do_bgfg(argv);
    return 1;
  }
  if (!strcmp(argv[0], "jobs")) { //jobs command
    printf("test2\n");
    listjobs(jobs);
    printf("test3\n");
    return 1;
  }
  printf("test4\n");
  return 0;     /* not a builtin command */
}
```

I input "jobs", but based on the test output (1-4-repeat), it's not registering. Does anyone know what might be going wrong?

Comment: What are you passing to the function, and what are you observing happens?

Comment: need more information. Where are the 'argv' coming from to the function. From 'main'?

Answer (score 4):

`argv[0]` points to the program name, not the first argument. `argv[1]` points to that, if the argument is present.

C Standard, [§ 5.1.2.2.1, Program Startup](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1):

> If the value of argc is greater than zero, the string pointed to by **argv[0] represents the program name**; argv[0][0] shall be the null character if the program name is not available from the host environment. If the value of argc is greater than one, the strings pointed to by argv[1] through argv[argc-1] represent the program parameters.

Emphasis mine.